# Removing HTML Tags ( &lt;p&gt; ) from Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, html-tag-summary

I have a column in my table which stores a paragraph like below :

**`&lt;p&gt;**75 Licenses for Workspace ONE Enterprise about to expire in October 2023 on Prem. Targeted to be migrated to VMC on AWS, exploiting the advantages of the cloud cost, scalability, manageability wise.**&lt;/p&gt;`**

I want to remove all the bold characters in the beginning (<p>) and in the ending (`&lt;/p&gt;`)
so that my expected result should be like this:

**75 Licenses for Workspace ONE Enterprise about to expire in October 2023 on Prem. Targeted to be migrated to VMC on AWS, exploiting the advantages of the cloud cost, scalability, manageability wise.**

Thank you.

I have already tried with:

```
regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace(
      regexp_replace(replace(replace(cta.SUCCESSCRITERIA,'&lt;p id=&quot;isPasted&quot;&gt;',''),'/p',''),
        r'<p [^<>]*>',   r'(Image) '),
        r'(&)([^&;]*)(;)', r'<\2>'
      ),r'\<[^<>]*\>',    ''
    )
```

But it resulted as this:

lt p gt 75 Licenses for Workspace ONE Enterprise about to expire in October 2023 on Prem. Targeted to be migrated to VMC on AWS, exploiting the advantages of the cloud cost, scalability, manageability wise. lt  p gt